# Selection criteria for microcontroller to read data from a car's CAN bus (from OBD2 to microcontroller)

Tags: microcontroller, can, obd, canopen

I want to read data from a car's CAN bus using a micro-controller. The micro-controller is used outside the car (via OBD to micro-controller).
A few micro-controllers i found with CAN interfaces are Teensy 4.0, ArduinoDue with dual CAN interface shield,LPC1768 etc.

Im not sure as to:

- On basis of what parameters to choose a microcontroller?
- What are the components need to make a connection from the OBD port to microcontroller, do we need a CAN transciever and a controller with a microcontroller? which i found being used in 
  [thread](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/186873/interpreting-can-bus-data-from-obd-port)[Interpreting CAN bus data from OBD port](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/186873/interpreting-can-bus-data-from-obd-port)

Im new to embedded systems.Any suggestion would be really helpful.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you choose a microcontroller with an integrated can controller then you need to buy only the CAN transceiver. If you want to use Arduino, then a CAN controller and a CAN transceiver or a single module with both CAN transceiver and CAN controller built in can be used.

Microcontroller decision is left to you depending on other product requirements such as memory, interfaces, performance and power.

Please take care of ESD, filtering and transient protection too.

Random [example](http://www.ti.com/product/TCAN4550-Q1) of a CAN controller

Comment: Thanks a lot User323693.. I have one more query.                                                                 If suppose i want to read data continuously and directly from CAN bus (500kbps-1Mbps transmission speed) and save it in external memory (without a logger):               what should be minimum microcontroller,transciever processing speed ?                               minimum buffers and memory?                                                                                               thanks a lot.. :)

Comment: @PjSwaroop we have to see the data throughput. 1Mbps is the clock frequency. External memory means what? A SPI Flash or a memory card? RAM and ROM requirements can only be estimated based on the application. But, with a microcontroller with built in CAN, the bottle neck I see is only the data transfer between internal RAM to external memory. Everything depends on the data throughput. Effective Data date in Kbps

Comment: Oh...The CAN bus effective data rate is 1 Mbps. I want to use one microcontroller(a node) to just receive all CAN bus data and store it in SD card for a limited amount of time(few mins). So for an incoming 1 Mbps data, how can i choose my microcontroller specs (processing speed, RAM etc) ?

Comment: http://www.esacademy.com/en/library/technical-articles-and-documents/can-and-canopen/selecting-a-can-controller.html                                   This thread talks about the scenario for a 1Mbps datarate.So in this case as microcontroller should process the message and save data to SD card at < 50microsec (say min 40micros). Therefore can we say the processing speed need to be atleast 1/40microsec = 25KHz.. Am i wrong?

Comment: @PjSwaroop the data throughput will be less. The baud rate is 1 Mbps. You have to really experiment. The higher RAM size enables more processing time for the incoming data.. a DMA based memory data transfer from RAM to the SD Card. Depending on the ping pong buffer size and the time needed to prepare the data, I would choose. I need to experiment too. If you are choosing for a small number of products, go with bigger RAM with pin compatible MCUs..with varying level of RAM(128kB) STM32F family itself will be sufficient I feel. Please go ahead and try. A dedicated CAN in the MCU will be helpful.

Comment: @PjSwaroop please give time. I will also read it really when I find time.

Comment: okay. I want to get data from a Car's CAN bus. I dont have an option to try it out as i need to buy the components.. but Maybe simulation is possible?   Thanks for all the info! Sure... please take your time :)

Answer (score 0):

> On basis of what parameters to choose a microcontroller?

Depends on your specification, obviously. As a rule of thumb, look for the most exotic item in the spec and take it from there. Do you have special requirements, limited board space, lots of GPIO etc etc.

Stuff like "Teensy 4.0, ArduinoDue with dual CAN interface shield" is for hobbyists. If you are doing a professional application, you can forget about these. Do you have access to PCB designers or are you forced to buy a board from someone else? If you have to buy a pre-made board, then that will severely limit your options.

Do you need automotive qualification? What's the EMI and ESD requirements? If these are tough, I'd start looking at the two manufacturers with the best reputation for automotive MCUs: NXP(Freescale) and Renesas. Though pretty much every MCU manufacturer got automotive parts nowadays.

But if your requirements are simply:

> If suppose i want to read data continuously and directly from CAN bus (500kbps-1Mbps transmission speed) and save it in external memory (without a logger)

Then you should pick a MCU with on-board CAN controller and most likely SPI. CAN transceivers are not often placed on-chip, so normally these need to be a separate, external IC. Using external CAN controllers, as done with Arduino, is stone age technology however, people stopped doing that over 20 years ago.

The CAN controller is a more rare peripheral than SPI, so that's perhaps the most "exotic" feature. It would perhaps be neat if you can DMA data straight from CAN to SPI, but probably not a mandatory feature.

Sounds like any mainstream Cortex M (such as LPC1768) would do the trick. These are available from pretty much every manufacturer, so from there you on should look for a *tool chain* that you like. This is important!

The free, Eclipse-based ones such as LPCxpresso are *abhorrent* (you get what you pay for). For professional use, instead consider something like Crossworks, IAR, Keil etc.